# How to turn off or turn on the Autolayout in code

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, autolayout, ios-autolayout

My app became something weird when I use Autolayout on iOS 7,so I want to know is there any way I can turn off Autolayout in code ? Anyone can help ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

In XIB You can Disable AutoLayout In Interface Builder Document

Comment: @bigCan i am glad i was able to help you :)

Answer (score 1):

[image]

When you create a project, Auto Layout is enabled by default. If you need to disable Auto Layout, choose `View > Utilities > Show File Inspector` and deselect the checkbox for Use Auto Layout.
if you are using `.xib` then unchecking the autolayout will disable autolayouts for only that particular controller, In such case you need to uncheck autolayouts in each and every `.xib`

Answer (score 0):

You can't. If you don't want to use autolayout then don't add any autolayout constrain anywhere (code/nib).